# animate text color and let other widgets waiting

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to create a "custom animation" for various texts. In my case, everything is done in sequence. I'm looking for a solution where when I add a widget to my method, the widget is played first after the first widget is finished

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._animate = TAnimation()

        self.textLabel = Label(self, bg="black", text="FontAnimation Text1", font=("Microsoft YuHei", 30))
        self.textLabel.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

        self.textLabel2 = Label(self, bg="black",  text="FontAnimation Text2", font=("Microsoft YuHei", 30))
        self.textLabel2.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

        self._animate.animateTextColor(self.textLabel, 0, 40, 50)
        self._animate.animateTextColor(self.textLabel2, 0, 120,  100) ## want to make other widgets "waiting" maybe one sec maybe 60 secs


class TAnimation(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.r = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.b = 0

    def animateTextColor(self, widget, start, wait, speed):
        if start < wait:
            widget.after(wait, lambda: self.animateTextColor(widget, start, wait, speed))
            start += 5
            print(start)
        elif start == wait:
            if self.b < 255:
                widget.configure(fg=self.rgbColor((self.r, self.g, self.b)))
                widget.after(speed, lambda : self.animateTextColor(widget,start, wait, speed))
                self.r += 1
                self.g += 1
                self.b += 1
            else:
                self.r = 0
                self.g = 0
                self.b = 0


    def rgbColor(self, rgb):
        return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mw = MainWindow()
    x1, y1 = mw.winfo_screenwidth() / 2, mw.winfo_screenheight() / 2
    x2, y2 = mw.winfo_screenwidth() / 4, mw.winfo_screenheight() / 4
    mw.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    mw.mainloop()
```

The problem here is that "widget2" assumes the same animation, actually this animation should only start when "widget1" is finished

Comment: Are you asking why the widget2 starts the animation before widget1 finishes the animation?

Comment: not exactly, because i know my values are wrong. but i dont know how to handle. i want a "waiting-time". first widget appears after 1 sec, the sceond one after 30 sec (for example). i want to control that in function values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to add items to a queue(list) and once one animation is completed start another.

check the example below

```py
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._animate = TAnimation()

        self.textLabel = Label(self, bg="black", text="FontAnimation Text1", font=("Microsoft YuHei", 30))
        self.textLabel.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

        self.textLabel2 = Label(self, bg="black",  text="FontAnimation Text2", font=("Microsoft YuHei", 30))
        self.textLabel2.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
        
        self._animate.addToQueue(self.textLabel, 5, 20)
        self._animate.addToQueue(self.textLabel2, 10, 5) ## want to make other widgets "waiting" maybe one sec maybe 60 secs

class TAnimation(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thresh = 255

    def animate(self, item, wait, rgb: list):

        if any(x>=self.thresh for x in rgb):
            return
        
        rgb = [x+1 for x in rgb]
        item.config(fg=self.rgbColor(rgb))

        self.after(wait, self.animate, item, wait, rgb)
                        
    def addToQueue(self, widget, wait, start_after: int):

        self.after(start_after, self.animate, widget, wait, [0, 0, 0])

    def rgbColor(self, rgb):
        return "#{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}".format(*rgb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mw = MainWindow()
    x1, y1 = mw.winfo_screenwidth() / 2, mw.winfo_screenheight() / 2
    x2, y2 = mw.winfo_screenwidth() / 4, mw.winfo_screenheight() / 4
    mw.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    mw.mainloop()
```

Comment: first thanks for the answer, i will keep that in mind. but itt doesnt answer my question. i want regular more widgets in this animation. so if i have 5 labels, i want to change the values. one widgets begins afters 10secs, the other one after one minute. but thanks

Comment: @JoeMo it definitely answers "actually this animation should only start when "widget1" is finished" part. If you want something else edit your question to add more clarity.

Comment: please read the first 9 words from my question : `
I'm looking for a way to create a "custom animation"`
so you have a very good example - and i will keep in mind that . but with that I smear everything. i want to animate one widget after the other. with other values.

Comment: @JoeMo check now

Comment: thanks. that was i meant. sorry if my question was unclear